# Windows 10 create a softlink to a file

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-prompt, symlink

On Windows 10 I am trying to create a soft link to a **file** through command prompt opened as an Administrator.

```
mklink "E:\Folder A\Folder B" "E:\Folder A\Folder C\bibliography.bib"
```

...where I want to create a soft link to bibliography.bib file into a folder B.

This throws me an error **Access denied**

What could be the reason?

Comment: at first in any case if you want create symbolic link to file - you need use file as src, not folder - otherwise link will be not correct worked. in your case i guess that  `E:\Folder A\Folder B` is already exist. and when `CreateSymbolicLinkW` call `ZwCreateFile` - it not use option `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` (because you not set `/D` switch). as result `ZwCreateFile` return error `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY` which converted to win32 error `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`

Comment: guess that if you add `/D` switch `mklink /D "E:\Folder A\Folder B" "E:\Folder A\Folder C\bibliography.bib"` you got error *Cannot create a file when that file already exists.*. you need use yet not existing file (if you use `mklink`) or empty file as link src

Answer (score 2):

Had to modify my command to

```
mklink "E:\Folder A\Folder B\bibliography.bib" "E:\Folder A\Folder C\bibliography.bib"
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all we can create symbolic link from **empty** directory to file or visa versa - from **empty** file to directory via [`FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364595(v=vs.85).aspx) - this is legal and will be work. and we can work with target file (or directory) through this symlink. say in case target is file - we can open and read it as file. but any file browser will be incorrect work with such symlink, because it will be use source file attribute `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` - as result try work with file like with directory or visa versa. because this exist sense use only `file -> file` or `directory -> directory` symbolic links (the src and target have the same `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` attribute - both have or not have)

also the `mklink` assume that symbolic link to be created file - yet not exist. internally it use `NtCreateFile` with `FILE_CREATE` disposition. as result we got error, if file already exist. if directory already exist and in call `NtCreateFile` we not use option `FILE_DIRECTORY_FILE` (mklink use this option when we use `/D` switch) - we got `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY` error. (*The file that was specified as a target is a directory and the caller specified that it could be anything but a directory.*). but `mklink` before display error message, first convert it to win32 error code, and it converted to.. `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. as result we and view `Access denied` message, despite the error have nothing common with access denied

if we want create symlink to file via mklink, we need select yet not existing file name(path) as symbolic link to be created